How to reconcile different teachings of Jesus regarding self defense?
Scripture states that vengeance belongs to God and we should let Him alone execute it.
Romans 12:19

vengeance is mine, says the Lord"

Jesus reinforced this statement by teaching that we should turn the other cheek to anyone who slaps us
Mathew 5:38-40

If anyone slaps you on the right cheek, turn to them the other cheek also

Interpret that as you may but it seems as if Jesus wanted us to give up self-defense to avoid violence, but then in some other instance Jesus showed he believes in the idea of self-defense when he said he could ask of his Father seven legions of angels to come and fight alongside him which is more or less self-defense.
Mathew 26:53

Do you think I cannot call on my Father, and he will at once put at my disposal more than twelve legions of angels?

It seems as if at some instance Jesus is against the idea of self defense and in some other he supports the idea of self defense, how does someone reconcile these two?

Briefly, I think it means to not have a short fuse, and to not seek revenge. To foster peace and debase strife, in other words.

Jesus was not defending Himself when He pointed out that He could.  It's worth noting, however, that when He spoke to soldiers, He did not tell them they should find another profession.

I’ve had it explained that in the cultural context that a slap was a public insult meant to drop someone down a social rank. This was so engrained in their honor shame culture that there was law built up around this. In this context, when someone slaps and rather than accept the insult, you give them the other cheek, they will have to use the other side of their hand which would have them hitting you as an equal vs a superior, further commentary on the ironic nature of the kingdom of God. Blessed are the poor in spirit for theirs is the kingdom of God

@Constantthin., Jesus could ask The Father for seven legions of angels if the Romans attacked him if his hour had not yet come, that is self defense very much unlike turn the other cheek

Revenge is not the same as defense. Defense is to prevent yourself (or others) from being harmed, revenge is retribution after you have been harmed.

@Barmar, sure. So the Bible says we should avoid violence, how do we avoid that violence when exercising self defense? Even Satan tried to push his luck and he had to be thrown out via a violent means

Blocking someone who is trying to hit you is not violence.

@Barmar, depends if he is using a weapon to attack you, what if he uses a knife? You will have to block that, probably disarm him by hitting his or her harm hard which is violence.

@Don I lack any history and that point would be quite pivotal for me. But does "I've had it explained" include its converse that "there's not going to be a source cited" If it's in a book I'll try to find it

@felixlxx I haven’t read it myself but here you go: The Gospel of Matthew: A Socio-Rhetorical Commentary

This would be better placed on christianity.stackexchange.com, as the Bible is not enough clear and various Christian denomination will likely have different solutions.

Let there be no doubt that God does not want His people to seek revenge:

Deut 32:35 - It is mine to avenge; I will repay. In due time their foot will slip; their day of disaster is near and their doom rushes upon them.”
Heb 10:30 - For we know him who said, “It is mine to avenge; I will repay,” and again, “The Lord will judge his people.”
Rom 12:19 - Do not take revenge, my dear friends, but leave room for God’s wrath, for it is written: “It is mine to avenge; I will repay,” says the Lord.

We have clear directions that God hates violence and judged some perpetrators harshly, Gen 6:11, Hab 1:2, 2:17, Jer 6:7, 20:8, Isa 60:18, Ps 11:5, 55:9, 58:2, Eze 7:23, 8:17, 28:16, 45:9, Prov 4:17, Micah 6:12, etc.  In Ps 11:5 we have this:

(NIV) - The LORD examines the righteous, but the wicked, those who love violence, he hates with a passion.
(CEV) - The LORD tests honest people, but despises those who are cruel and love violence.

Further, we have the laws of warfare as enumerated in Deut 20.  In particular, the rules of engagement included this in V10-13 –book of

When you approach a city to fight against it, you are to make an offer
of peace.  If they accept your offer of peace and open their gates,
all the people there will become forced laborers to serve you. But if
they refuse to make peace with you and wage war against you, lay siege
to that city.  When the LORD your God has delivered it into your hand,
you must put every male to the sword.

The NT has numerous commands of God to forgive (Col 3:13, Eph 4:32, Matt 6:14, 15, 18:35, etc) and to be loving and kind (John 13:34, 35, Luke 6:34-36, 1 John 4:8, 16, Eph 5:1, 2, etc).
Now, of the OP quoted texts - ALL say the same thing to avoid violence; even the last one in Matt 26:51-53 - let me quote the context:

At this, one of Jesus’ companions drew his sword and struck the
servant of the high priest, cutting off his ear.
“Put your sword back in its place,” Jesus said to him. “For all who
draw the sword will die by the sword. Are you not aware that I can
call on My Father, and He will at once put at My disposal more than
twelve legions of angels?

Note what Jesus is effectively saying to Peter - do not use violence - I could ask the Father to provide twelve legions of angels to protect me; but I refuse to do this because I do not want to use violence!!!
Thus, there is little justification for violence in the Bible except at God's direct instruction (However, beware of anyone who claims such direct instruction!)

what about defending yourself? What if someone tried to attack you and you have a family to feed? Will you put back your sword? and if you forgive him, how sure are you he will return at a future time and try to do the same when you least expect it

@SoFewAgainstSoMany - good question - defense is reasonable but that is another question.

It's interesting that this answer was accepted even though it doesn't even mention "self defence". Then again, neither do any of the scriptures the question appears to be asking about. I still haven't been able to figure out what "how does someone reconcile these two?" means when there is only one.

@RayButterworth - self defense is permissible but in a non-violent and non-vengeful way.  That is tricky!

@Dottard, yes, but the question doesn't provide any scripture that relates to self-defence.  The example of the twelve legions is about resisting arrest, not self-defence.

@Dottard, a much better example of self-defence would be Luke 4:30
"But he passing through the midst of them went his way,". But that again doesn't in any way cause a conflict with the other scriptures.  This question is like a strawman argument: set up a situation that doesn't exist and then ask why it contradicts.

@RayButterworth - good point, agreed.

A project to reconcile Jesus' teachings regarding self-defense bears an immediate problem that the teachings aren't about self-defense.
Hypothetically (but patently) English situates self-defense into speakers' popular hotch-potch conception of oriental philosophy. So it's familiar cliche for martial arts to be taught in terms of balancing an opponent's energy. "Chi" is in popular usage but the 'I Ching' isn't on bookshelves.
====
μὴ ἑαυτοὺς ἐκδικοῦντες, ἀγαπητοί, ἀλλὰ δότε τόπον τῇ ὀργῇ· γέγραπται γάρ “Ἐμοὶ ἐκδίκησις, ἐγὼ ἀνταποδώσω, λέγει Κύριος.”
====
The OP's question might be approached at a Word Study level by asking if ἐκδίκησις=Vengeance corresponds productively with our idea of 'Self Defense'.
Straightaway, by its parts an ἐκδίκησις is an out-judge-ing. And if it is God's it might be don't hit people back because I'll judge you... which in English technical-legal language is more like "I have jurisdiction".
Very different from don't hit people back because it's my job to hit them.
And that highlights that a converse is being taken from Ἐμοὶ ἐκδίκησις . God is talking about what we can do, but we are reading it as a statement about what God can do.
The place he says it is Deuteronomy 32:35, and we need to be prepared for the likelihood that Paul is quoting a Greek translation from Hebrew, and that therefore there's a question how much he intends to bring over from the Hebrew word.
ἐν ἡμέρᾳ ἐκδικήσεως ἀνταποδώσω = Vengeance is mine, and recompense
Matching Paul's “Ἐμοὶ ἐκδίκησις, ἐγὼ ἀνταποδώσω.
So the question is open.
The Hebrew word ἐκδικήσεως translated was נָקָם֙
https://biblehub.com/hebrew/5358.htm
Looking at Strongs and Brown-Driver-Briggs, this is an emphatic word used for God's punishment of those who breach the covenant, avenging murder and spilt blood. This might be why our translations leave behind the legal senses of ἐκδίκησις - those are brought in by the Greek.
To check this, we can at this late point come back to a Greek lexicon. Liddell & Scott has edikazo of a judge finally settling a lawsuit (Aristophanes Knights, 50) and the other examples are all technical-legal.
ἐκδικέω might be a bit more emphatic/less legal. There's avenge/punish a crime. Most of the examples are LXX or NT. Luke uses it of specifically legal protection at Luke 18:3-5.
ἐκδίκησις the noun - 'an avenging' / to give satisfaction. But see Polybius 3.8.10
δόγματι μόνον τὴν ἐκδίκησιν ποιησαμένους = = [The Carthaginians could have ensured their safety] by merely passing a decree.
===
Usually a lexicon entry carries more weight than an argument from etymology, but I submit that for this word there are too few surviving examples and the LXX's translators having adopted it for Hebrew nā-qām has created something of a circularity whereby we now can't tell what they intended by doing so.
The root -δίκ- emphasizes jurisdiction, which the LXX's translators might perhaps have found in nā-qām (or they may have wanted to add it for theological reasons we can't tell). English translators have a dilemma: the fact we can't detect any judicial sense in nā-qām isn't sufficient to remove that sense from the translation of ἐκδίκησις.
For nā-qām Strongs only has 17 occurrences, nearly all of which are reserved to a just God.
If it stands, that's a nice condundrum: Vengeance is God's, and so emphatically so that we mortals can't even tell what it is. [humour] Perhaps it is a sort of nice cake [/humour]
What can be said from the remaining 17 occurrences is it's used about murder and in military contexts. It's not the liquidated damages on the back of Solomon's bills-of-lading for timber. It's not Mr. Wilson getting his apples back.
It can be malicious (Ezekiel 25:15) and the same place suggests there can be ἐκδίκησις and counter-ἐκδίκησις.
== == == == == == == ==
A hotch-potch conception of oriental philosophy might help us though. It's often conjectured many ideas moved up and down the spice roads in long-lost antiquity and crop up again in the oddest places.
Self-defense isn't vengeance. It's not "If you kill my dog, I'ma slay your cat" or "Judas fought against the children of Esau in Idumea at Arabattine, because they besieged Gael". That destructive, worst-case, eye-for-an-eye retribution might be what God's reserving to himself in Deuteronomy. We might not gain a precise weighting of how much blood must be in the scale, or whether grievous bodily harm is in there as well as murder - but God or just our text doesn't have to delineate what's reserved to him for the reason it's beyond us.
Paul's usage in Romans 12 isn't in an immediate or Old Testament type context of military reprisals or punishment-killings. But if he's anticipating that these matters will be absolutely mortal for himself, and eventually many in his immediate audience, we know with hindsight he was absolutely right.
If we are fortunate enough to live in the countries where Christianity isn't punishable by death or subject to severe and government-condoned persecution, then what we should derive from that is a pastoral question.
If Paul can tell his followers not to retaliate against his, or their own, killers, we can say that speaks to what we should do about that menacing kid next door, or Terminator X's household pets. But that is by hyperbole on our part and we should remember the advice is still very direct to many Christians.
========================================================
Matthew 5:38-40 is being brought into juxtaposition with Romans 12. But I'll contend it's most useful because of this exact point of scale.
Jesus is quoting Exodus 21:23–27 : עַיִן תַּחַת עַיִן, = = [only] one eye for one eye
Which of course is a proposition he believes. And one reason he can believe it, side-by-side with his contention here "Do not resist the one who is evil." is that the emphasis wasn't on cruel and unusual forms of corporal punishment, but on commensuracy. Which can be seen in God's 'vengeance' at the scale above us. (in that nā-qām isn't for Philistine cities being laid waste because someone there ate a wrong meat or shaved in the wrong direction). And in our own time, and probably any other, proportionality and measuredness are not a universal default setting of humanity's.
Jesus qualifies "Do not resist the one who is evil." with the examples of someone hitting us, someone stealing our cloak, someone making us walk too far, and someone asking to borrow money.
And that fits neatly underneath the scale offered by Exodus (grievous bodily harm) and underneath the scale offered by Deuteronomy (blood-retaliation at the level of nation-states). It looks like an expository division-into-three.
The trivial - we prosecute            - smaller than the human scale - money
The criminal - the courts prosecute   - equal to the human scale - blood
The transcendental - God prosecutes         - larger than the human scale - life
At each of these levels, by Jesus' addition, the scripture now has worked examples following a consistent principle: commensuracy.
There can be derived a further principle: of supervision or oversight. Which also finds expression in both ancient and modern jurisprudence. Courts have levels at which they can try things, and we are a court too. For those ideas elsewhere in scripture there's "lex dei in corde ipsius" in the Psalms, being the spokesperson of (God as the true) judge involves a duplication of the law into the human heart. And the parable of the talents - each of the servants is given a jurisdiction proportionate to the justice they have inside them.
More tentatively, if we find some asceticism in Jesus' other teachings on money, he might here be doing something along the lines of demoting financial disputes into the trivial, whilst holding that the courts (who we know will kill him) ought to refer up to God when a matter escalates from bloodshed (such as eyes and teeth) to the spilling of human life (=nephesh).
There are other places in the scripture where this hypothesis might be tested, such as the woman caught in adultery: is that reserving the death penalty to God distinct from disapplying it. But it would too much divert from the OP's question to explore that.
======================
Something which literature, the texts, and finally our readings - sadly lose is colloquialism. The 4 examples Jesus offers are markedly everyday and if they have a converse (which we can extract exegetically) that supplies a "nice" bit of folk-wisdom, that's to be noted, at least in case it turns up on a scroll somewhere.
The other cheek: ἄλλην σιαγόνα.
ἄλλος is straightforward and our idiom is still close enough: another of similar type. So with definite article we take it as "the other" but English idiom forces the definite and the indefinite into marked distinction. τὴν ἄλλην also needs to distinguish our other cheek from someone else's cheek . But this never confused anyone.
σιαγών is really the jaw-bone, which English treats as singular. We're here in a contrast between τὴν δεξιὰν... τὴν ἄλλην. So to create the to-us simple image, the Greek might have needed to turn a monistic jawbone into a pair of dualistic cheeks. Let's check this.
Big Liddell & Scott (1882) has not many examples but there is Aristotle P.A.3.7.4. That's now a broken citation and De Partibus Animalium isn't on Perseus Project and the scanned versions on Archive.org have broken OCR meaning the text isn't searchable. But we've got... of Crocodiles "το την σιαγόνα" jaw (II.7, around 660a26) is singular but as we'll see for this species he might be talking about one jaw of two. "τας σιαγόνας" man and quadrupeds move their jaws up and down - that will be multiple species each of whose jaws is here in the plural. 658b30 is better "eis stenon tas diagonas"=those animals whose jaws project forward and become gradually narrower. Also the crocodile "κινειν σιαγόνα η την κάτωθεν αύτό" moves the upper jaw instead of the lower one - [humour] Aristotle is super interested in why crocodiles' have their jaws the wrong way round [/humour] This suggests the word refers more to the upper and lower jaw than the left and right cheek.
Aristotle might be using words in technical anatomical/medical senses, but he's still on the bookshelves in Matthew's time. For him the jaw seems to be internal and mechanical. Creatures have two of them: an upper and a lower one. So by a small extension the singular marks out the upper or the lower or (as here) the left or the right, but in the absence of that qualifier, our jaws (and therefore in translation our cheeks) are plural.
Jaws. I've got two of them. From this:-
Simplex: If you hit my right one, you can have the other.
Converse: I've only got two, so if you hit the other one as well, that's your lot.
This is why Jesus doesn't just make the sweeping, didactic statement "Do not resist the one who is evil." and leave it at that. It requires qualification.
By qualifying it with the cheeks, he brings in a folksy "fool-me-once" sentiment. We can't tell if it's a popular aphorism. But it sets an immediate and clear route of escalation from what I have proposed is the trivial court, in which we are our own judges, to the criminal one in which the judges are the judges. God's law is not diminished in the courts of the trivial and criminal, but fully-revealed in microcosm.
I contend that what the scripture prescribes for the good man, and what it clarifies by this reference to "the other cheek", isn't boundless masochism, or tolerance-in-absurdum, but the humble adoption of God's law into his heart, and the recognition of when a dispute requires escalation to a higher judge.

Too long didn't read brother but I get your point. +1 Upvoted

If I don't resists someone who is evil he might cause harm by hurting people close like family, its better to prevent than to regret, which is a guilt you will never forgive yourself for

@SoFewAgainstSoMany to extrapolate I think would need to bring in other verses and I'm a new user so don't yet know the protocol. But if LXX were right to see endikesis in the MT's na-qam, then there is a judgement and therefore a judge to whom we must make the case. In Matthew 6:5 (emphasizing its legal language) our case is so  unwinnable that we'll need to ask our barrister to pay the penalty for us.

and with that you mean Jesus paid the penalty because humans cannot live the perfect life as required by God, true


How to reconcile different teachings of Jesus regarding self defense?

None of Jesus's recorded teachings bear on self defense.  In particular,

Romans 12:19

vengeance is mine, says the Lord"


Vengeance is not defense in any sense, neither of self nor of another.  It is repayment for a (perceived) wrong done, thus a form of justice.  Striking someone to repay them for striking me is vengeance.  Striking someone to prevent them from striking me [again] is defense.

Jesus reinforced this statement by teaching that we should turn the
other cheek to anyone who slaps us

You are right to connect this to the previous, because it, too, is about payback, not about defense.  The lead-in to the section (Matt 5:38-39) is

You have heard that it was said, ‘Eye for eye, and tooth for tooth.’ But I tell you [...]

Furthermore, the cheek slap should be understood not as an attack, to which defense would be relevant, but as a personal insult.  That's a whole different kettle of fish.

Interpret that as you may but it seems as if Jesus wanted us to give up self-defense to avoid violence,

Again, none of that is about self-defense at all, and certainly not about physical self-defense.
There are human traditions that renounce physical violence in any form, including for self-defense.  Some of those are inspired by Christianity, but that is not among Jesus's specific teachings.

but then in some other instance Jesus showed he believes in the idea of self-defense when he said he could ask of his Father seven legions of angels to come and fight alongside him which is more or less self-defense.

Your paraphrase loses sight of the actual scripture here.  This occurs when the mob sent by the Jewish chief priests and elders arrives to capture Jesus.  From Matt 26:51-54 (NIV):

one of Jesus’ companions reached for his sword, drew it out and struck
the servant of the high priest, cutting off his ear.
“Put your sword back in its place,” Jesus said to him, “for all who
draw the sword will die by the sword. Do you think I cannot call on my
Father, and he will at once put at my disposal more than twelve
legions of angels? But how then would the Scriptures be fulfilled that
say it must happen in this way?”

Note well that nothing there is about Jesus personally fighting or defending himself. It is about who else could or would defend him if he wanted it.  Even so, supposing that Jesus would ever need to engage in combat is absurd.  If he did not want to be captured, he would have had no need to fight to prevent it.  For example, consider the incident recounted in Luke 4, where he was surrounded by an angry mob intent on throwing him off a cliff, and he was able simply to walk away.

It seems as if at some instance Jesus is against the idea of self defense and in some other he supports the idea of self defense, how does someone reconcile these two?

Jesus nowhere speaks to the concept of self-defense, physical or otherwise.  There is no conflict in that regard, and no need for any reconciliation.
You should understand, however, that God does at times condone physical violence, not only defensive in nature but even offensive.  When he brings the Israelites to the promised land, for example, he explicitly instructs them to conquer all the cities within and kill or drive out the people living there.  Or for a NT example, you could consider Jesus personally, physically driving the money lenders out of the temple courts.

Answer
According to my understanding, we need to distinguish between self-defense and vengeance. The former is when we try to preserve our life and the latter is not directly involved with this. Jesus Christ distinguishes the two.
Explanation
Self-Defense:- Jesus, as a Person who believed and followed the Old Testament Scripture was aware of the Law that differentiated between intentional murder (Num 35:20) and accidental killing (Num 35:22-23).
The latter could be an accident or an effort of self-defense when you wanted to preserve your life from, say, a criminal. So, God has given provisions for the same in detail.
The New Testament Approach
But in the New Testament, a true believer must depend on the living God for self-defense. The believer is supposed to be vigilant and alert for his life. Jesus said:

“But when they persecute you in this city, flee to another” (Mat
10:23).

This is the Christian self-defense. Jesus set several examples. Let us see one sample:

“Then from that day, they took counsel that they might kill Him.
Then Jesus no longer walked publicly among the Jews, but went away
from there into the country near a deserted place, to a city being
called Ephraim, and stayed there with His disciples” (John 11:53-54).

This is how Jesus defended His life until His time came.
Apostles followed the same procedure. Let us see one example:

“And when many days were fulfilled, the Jews plotted together to do
away with him. But their plot was known to Saul. And they carefully
watched the gates both by day and by night so as to do away with
him. But taking him by night, the disciples let him down through
the wall, lowering in a basket. And Saul arriving in Jerusalem, he
tried to be joined to the disciples” (Acts 9:23-26).

So, this is the case for self-defense for a Christian.
Vengeance:- Vengeance is taking revenge for some wrong done to oneself. There need not be any threat to one’s life. It is here that Jesus said:

“You have heard that it was said: "An eye for an eye, and a tooth for
a tooth;" [There is no threat to life here] but I say to you, Do not
resist the evil; but whoever strikes you on the right cheek [There is
no threat to life here], turn the other to him also. And to him
desiring to sue you, and to take your tunic [There is no threat to
life here], allow him also to have the coat. And whoever shall compel
you to go one mile [There is no threat to life here], go two with
him. He asking you to give, and he wishing to borrow from you [There
is no threat to life here], do not turn away” (Mat 5:38-42).

The same practice is advised by an apostle of Jesus:

“Do not pay anyone back evil for evil, but focus your thoughts on what
is right in the sight of all people. If possible, so far as it depends
on you, live in peace with all people. Do not take revenge, dear
friends, but leave room for God's wrath. For it is written,
"Vengeance belongs to me. I will pay them back, declares the Lord."
But "if your enemy is hungry, feed him. For if he is thirsty,
give him a drink. If you do this, you will pile burning coals on his head." Do not be conquered by evil, but conquer evil with good”
(Rom 12:17-21).

[These are still revolutionary according to the standard of the modern enlightened world; just imagine how revolutionary these must have been 2000 years before!]
So, a true believer of Jesus Christ cannot and should not take revenge on anyone. He must leave the same to the living God.
Hyperbole
Many people are worried about one specific statement of Jesus Christ:

“But if anyone slaps you on the right cheek, turn to him the other
also” (Mat 5:39).

If one wants to practice this, one will have sleepless nights!
But the fact is, Jesus said this in a hyperbolic sense.

“When Jesus said this, one of the guards there slapped him and
said, "How dare you talk like that to the High Priest!" (John 18:22).

Did we expect Jesus to turn His other cheek?

“Jesus answered him, "If I have said anything wrong, tell everyone
here what it was. But if I am right in what I have said, why do you
hit me?" (verse 23).

Jesus didn’t turn and show His other cheek but at the same time He didn’t retaliate. And that is exactly what He meant when He used the hyperbole.
Conclusion
Lord Jesus Christ has clearly distinguished between self-defense and taking vengeance and has accordingly given instructions to His followers. There need not be any ambiguity in any of these.

Yeah I agree and the other example is the story of Moses killing the Egyptian, though Moses didn't do it accidentally, it was intentional and that's why the second Egyptian   scared him  and he ran away because he thought it to be a secret

I would say if you're being actively attacked and threatened you can defend yourself proportionally, and if you are defending someone else you definitely are to fight whoever is attacking. However if they have stopped attacking you must immediately stop as well and you should never escalate the conflict if at all possible. Your first action should be to seek peace and your last action should be to seek peace. Never try to hunt down your attacker to hurt him/her or their family as that would be vengeance and that belongs to God.
God also says that he appoints those in authority and so I would say reporting the attacker to the police or whoever has authority to judge and punish isn't going against God's instructions and is using the systems God has put in place to seek justice. But always pray that God's Justice is applied and pray for the one who attacked you that they will repent of their lifestyle and turn to God.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Not to defend oneself against an enemy encroaching upon your land to plunder, rape and kill, is either to be mad or to be poisoned by Tolsovian poisonous doctrine of "non-resistance to evil by violence", or in its Indian-Ghandian version of "Satiagraha". This has nothing to do with Christianity.
Further, if you are personally humiliated, insulted, calumniated, or even physically offended, it is just to defend oneself, and even, it is unjust and pusillanimous not to do so. Sin is to hate an offender, but it is not sin to stop him by a just action. You can even kill an offender and it can not be a sin, even if it may be a legal transgression and you may go to prison, but, again, it may not be a sin. But if you do not act violently against an offender, not break law, but hate him in your heart, you are committing an act of murder and sin, according to words of the Savior.
Thus, when He does not defend Himself and does not destroy his destroyers - for He could destroy both Jewish leaders and Roman authorities including the Emperor and the entire senate, with all the legions subjected to them, but had He done so, humanity would have followed Him out of fear, and He would have utterly failed to make real friends of Him, who would follow Him out of a sincere, free decision and love, without being afraid of Him as of some almighty despot.
Thus, He can defend Himself - as He often did, for He was many times on brink of being stoned and nobody, by human powers, would have escaped those attempts of His foes - and not defend Himself, all depends on His divine vision and plan of saving mankind.
The only thing He cannot do is to hate a sinner and to wish his destroying. He has mercy even on poor fallen spirits - demons - and how much more He has mercy on any vile humans, be it Pol Pot, Hitler, or Al Capone.

A good strategy for self-defence is to follow the so called ABC formula. “A” stands for being Aware of where the dangers lurks and to not visit these places. “B” stands for Bolt, if one accidentally finds oneself at the wrong place, at the wrong time. And “C” stands for Confront, if the two first steps have failed. At this stage one can ask oneself how life threatening the situation is and if one is prepared to take the magical mystery tour across the universe.
Ref: 1 Thess 5
Invalids, singles, and older Christians are generally more prepared for this adventure than others. Jesus talked about this, stating that this day would come unexpectedly, like a thief in the night, for most. Adding that as spring comes before summer, some people will understand the signs of the times, and be warned about their approaching departure, giving them time to get ready for it.
Ref: Mat 24; Luke 14 and 21
